# Preferences for four ladies and four gentlemen where one proposer receives his/her lowest-ranked choice,...

Tags: combinatorics

How can I determine a list of preferences for four ladies and four gentlemen where one proposer receives his or her lowest-ranked choice, and the rest of the proposers receive their penultimate (second to last) choice.

This is a Gale-Shapely stable marriage question, but I am having trouble coming up with a list that makes the conditions true.

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. Does the criterion have to hold for just one pairing? For any pairing? For the 'best' pairing? (And what does 'best' mean exactly?) If the pairing is given beforehand, then you can just write down a list for every person such that his chosen partner is at the right spot in the list.

Comment: Are you sure that it not the reviewers who get such a poor result?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It turns out i really like these puzzles. The numbers propose:

\begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox{1} & c&b&d&a \\
\mbox{2} & c & d&b&a \\
\mbox{3} & b & d&c&a \\
\mbox{4} & b & c&d&a \\
\ \\
\mbox{a} & 1 & x&x&x \\
\mbox{b} & 2 & 1&3&4 \\
\mbox{c} & 3 & 4&2&1 \\
\mbox{d} & 4 & 1&3&2 \end{array}